# how can i implement function, when user dont complete UserProfiling its not move to ContentView. otherwise

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

## this is UserProfiling view model

```
class UserProfiling: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedLanguages: [String] = []
    @Published var isProfileCompleted: Bool =  false
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var userId: String?
    
    init()  {
            if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                self.userId = userId
                checkUserProfiling()
            }
        }
    
    func checkUserProfiling() -> Bool {
        guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return false
        }
        
        db.collection("users").document(userId).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting user profiling: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let snapshot = snapshot, snapshot.exists {
                let data = snapshot.data()
                if let isProfileCompleted = data?["isProfileCompleted"] as? Bool {
                        self.isProfileCompleted = isProfileCompleted
                }
            }
        }
        return isProfileCompleted
    }
    
    
    func saveUserProfiling(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        print(selectedLanguages)
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        
        let documentRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
        
        documentRef.setData([
            "selectedLanguages": selectedLanguages,
            "isProfileCompleted": true
        ], merge: true) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error saving user profiling data to firestore :\(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false)
            } else {
                print("User profiling data saved to firestore successfully.")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isProfileCompleted = true
                }
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## this is file MoovieApp.

this is for my user management access.

```
//
//  MoovieApp.swift
//  Moovie
//
//  Created by Putut Yusri Bahtiar on 26/03/23.
//

import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore

@main
struct MoovieApp: App {
    @StateObject var sessionAuth = SessionAuth()
    @StateObject var userProfiling = UserProfiling()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if sessionAuth.isLoggedIn {
                if userProfiling.isProfileCompleted {
                    ContentView()
                        .environmentObject(sessionAuth)
                        .environmentObject(userProfiling)
                } else {
                    UserProfilingView()
                        .environmentObject(sessionAuth)
                        .environmentObject(userProfiling)
                }
            } else {
                LoginView()
                    .environmentObject(sessionAuth)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**i want when user first time login or dont complete  UserProfiling its not move to ContentView. if user has completed UserProfiling its gonna move to ContentView automatically.**

when im trying its like not move to ContentView, but if i close app and open again its going ContentView.

Comment: What do you do in UserProfilingView to update session auth an user profile ? You may have missed some update (on the main queue)

Comment: i just print the result,

userProfiling.saveUserProfiling { success in
                            if success {
                                print("success add data")
                            } else {
                                print("error add data")
                            }

Comment: Where do you set : sessionAuth.isLoggedIn ?

Comment: i set on my SessionAuth.swift its different file.

Comment: I asked this because this code is the one that should make the content of the view change. In what you show we do not see where it is called.

Comment: i have 2 model view or i just use that on SessionView ?

UserProfiling.swift this for user after completed the action
SessionAuth.swift this for user login and regiter

so i make on my MoovieApp, if user has been login, if user has completed the userprofiling its show to ContentView. if user not completed the userprofiling it cant show the ContentView.